# In an integer array with N elements , find the minimum k elements?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Worst-case O(n) algorithm for doing k-selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358912/worst-case-on-algorithm-for-doing-k-selection)

Given the following question :

```
In an integer array with N elements , find the minimum k elements (k << N)
```

You can assume that `N` is a large number.

I'm thinking about a minimum heap , anyone has a better solution ?

Regards

Comment: @DavidM: No! exam question (preparing for an exam)

Comment: The heap-based solution has running time O(N log N). I think the intention (since k<<N) is to find a solution with O(kN) running time (which may have better performance if k<<N).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746648/throwing-the-fattest-people-off-of-an-overloaded-airplane

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If K << N, min heap is good enough because creation of heap is O(n), and if K << N selecting first K items is at most O(N), otherwise you could use [selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) to find Kth smallest element in `O(n)` then select numbers which are smaller than found item. (Sure if some numbers are equal to Kth element select till fill `K` items).

Comment: A min heap might actually be slower than a naive implementation.  I know for a fact that it's slower if k == 1.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: After finding the `Kth` smallest number , then I should use the Partition algorithm ?

Comment: @ron After you find the `Kth` smallest number, all you need to do is iterate the array again and any number `< Kth smallest` is in your solution, until you have `k` items. So `O(n) + O(n) = O(2n) ~ O(n)`

Comment: @ron, just iterate array, and select numbers which are smaller than or equal to Kth smallest number, then if number of found item is bigger than `K` drop some items which are equal to Kth smallest number.

Comment: @Wug, Sure for K=1,2,3 creating heap is not good, but when we don't know anything about `K` except `K << N`, we can't trust naive approach. e.g K = sqrt(N) << N, but naive approach causes to `n sqrt(n)` but heap is less than `O(n logn)`

Comment: You can do this with an algorithm that runs in O(N*log(K)) time.  Using an unmodified heap is O(N*log(N)).  If you bound the heap (i.e. give it a maximum size of K) then the insertion time for it is O(log(K)).

Comment: @Wug, I offered an algorithm in O(N), heap is simple for implementation so I offered it as first option, also it's not `O(N log N)` it's O(N + k * log(N)) . Be careful creating heap of size `N` is O(N) not O(nlogn), deleting from heap takes time.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: depends on the heap implementation.  Insertion into a binary heap is O(log(N)).  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)

Comment: @Wug, I'm talking about creating heap not inserting in heap of size `n`, please check CLRS or other algorithmic text books too see why creating (min) heap is `O(n)`. If you couldn't find it, ask it in another question I'll answer it (but better place for this question is cs.stackexchange.com).

Comment: OK, but that still leaves the disadvantage of either needing to reorder the array (which may not be an option) or to duplicate it.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

Sort the array (quicksort or heapsort are great for integer arrays), and iterate to k

Comment: Unless k is large, this is slower than k O(n) searches.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this one in O(N*log(K)).  Pseudocode:

```
haz array[N]
haz output[k] (itz a list)

i iteratez on array with array[N] az element:
    i insertz element into output (i maintainz strict ordering)
    i removez largest element of output when output size iz bigger than k
```

Requires:

- N list removals from end (N * O(1))
- at most N sort-maintaining list inserts (N * O(log(listsize)))

list's size is bounded by K

Thus, O(N * log(K)) time.