# Get the k-largest elements from an array whit n Elements, where n is much larger than k

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Suppose you have an unsorted array of length n. Now you want to take the k-largest elements from the array. We also know that n is much larger than k.

My naive idea is to sort the array and output the k-largest elements. That would cost O(nlog(n)). Is there a more efficient algorithm that takes advantage of the fact that n is much larger than k ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In an integer array with N elements , find the minimum k elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12057195/in-an-integer-array-with-n-elements-find-the-minimum-k-elements)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, more effective algorithms do exist.

Get k first elements, build **min**-heap containing these k elements.

Traverse through other elements. If current item is larger than heap top, remove top and insert current item.

After the end heap will contain k largest elements.

Complexity is `O(N*logK)`

---

Also consider [QuickSelect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) algorithm  with average time O(n) (while it has worst case up to quadratic)