# Converting a Scala method to Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The below Scala method returns the k nearest neighbours of an `Array` :

```
  def getNearestNeighbours(distances: Array[((String, String), Double)], k: Int, label: String) = {                    //| label: String)List[((String, String), Double)]

    distances.filter(v => v._1._1.equals(label) || v._1._2.equals(label)).sortBy(_._2).take(k)
  }
```

I want to run this function in parallel. I can try converting the `Array` to an `RDD` but type `RDD` does not support the functions `.sortBy(_._2).take(k)` Is there a way to emulate this method in Spark/Scala ?

A possible solution is to modify the method so that the RDD is converted to an Array everytime the method is called, but I think this is computationally expensive for large RDD's ? :

```
  def getNearestNeighbours(distances: RDD[((String, String), Double)], k: Int, label: String) = {                    //| label: String)List[((String, String), Double)]

    distances.collect.filter(v => v._1._1.equals(label) || v._1._2.equals(label)).sortBy(_._2).take(k)
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDD does have `sortByKey` method, which sorts RDDs of pairs by the first element, so if you can create `RDD[(Double, (String, String))]` instead of  `RDD[((String, String), Double)]` (or just call `rdd.map(p => (p._2, p._1)`), you can translate the algorithm directly. It also has `take`, but the documentation says:

> Return an array with the first n elements of the dataset. Note that this is currently not executed in parallel. Instead, the driver program computes all the elements.

So I wouldn't expect this to work *well*.

Besides, if the data fits on one machine, just working with Arrays (or parallel collections) is likely to be faster. Spark does what it can to minimize overhead, but distributed sorting is going to have *some* overhead anyway!

In addition, sorting the entire array/RDD/other collection if you just need the least `n` elements is a bad idea (again, especially in cases when you'd want to use Spark). You need a selection algorithm like ones described in [Worst-case O(n) algorithm for doing k-selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358912/worst-case-on-algorithm-for-doing-k-selection) or [In an integer array with N elements , find the minimum k elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12057195/in-an-integer-array-with-n-elements-find-the-minimum-k-elements). Unfortunately, they aren't available in Scala standard library or in Spark (that I know of).

Comment: Great answer, except you've missed `RDD.top`! It does exactly the (distributed) heap-based selection that you mention. It's great. (I've added a short answer pointing out `RDD.top`.)

Answer (score 2):

Do not `collect` the RDD. It pulls all the data to one machine. Change your input so it is keyed by the *negative* distance (`RDD[Double, (String, String)]`) and then use `RDD.top(k)`.