# Fastest method of getting k smallest numbers in unsorted list?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

What is the fastest method to get the k smallest numbers in an unsorted list of size N using python?

Is it faster to sort the big list of numbers, and then get the k smallest numbers, or to get the k smallest numbers by finding the minimum in the list k times, making sure to remove the found minimum from the search before the next search?

Comment: I highly advise against finding the minimum k times.

Comment: yes, i spose thats k^2 lookups

Comment: It's fine to do this in Python, but it's actually a fairly language-independent problem.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann: sure, but Python comes with batteries included: `import heapq; result = heapq.nsmallest(k, inputlist)`.

Comment: the fastest depends on `k`,`N`, on the magnitude of the integers (if they are integers), on available hardware (e.g., whether it makes sense to offload the work to GPU using parallel heapsort), on Python implementation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use a heap queue; it can give you the K largest or smallest numbers out of a list of size N in O(NlogK) time.

The Python standard library includes the [`heapq` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html), complete with a [`heapq.nsmallest()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest) ready implemented:

```
import heapq

k_smallest = heapq.nsmallest(k, input_list)
```

Internally, this creates a heap of size K with the first K elements of the input list, then iterating over the remaining N-K elements, pushing each to the heap, then popping off the largest one. Such a push and pop takes log K time, making the overall operation O(NlogK).

The function also optimises the following edge cases:

- If K is 1, the `min()` function is used instead, giving you a O(N) result.
- If K >= N, the function uses sorting instead, since O(NlogN) would beat O(NlogK) in that case.

A better option is to use the [introselect algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910641/how-to-get-indices-of-n-maximum-values-in-a-numpy-array), which offers an O(n) option. The only implementation I am aware of is using the [`numpy.partition()` function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html):

```
import numpy

# assuming you have a python list, you need to convert to a numpy array first
array = numpy.array(input_list)
# partition, slice back to the k smallest elements, convert back to a Python list
k_smallest = numpy.partition(array, k)[:k].tolist()
```

Apart from requiring installation of `numpy`, this also takes N memory (versus K for `heapq`), as a copy of the list is created for the partition.

If you only wanted indices, you can use, for either variant:

```
heapq.nsmallest(k, range(len(input_list)), key=input_list.__getitem__)  # O(NlogK)
numpy.argpartition(numpy.array(input_list), k)[:k].tolist()  # O(N)
```

Comment: If you scroll down, there's a quick discussion on doing it in O(n) time.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann: nope, because selecting the kth smallest item is glossed over a little too quickly there. That's what the heap queue does!

Comment: Selection of the kth element in an unordered list can be done in n time and constant memory. The heap queue does neither.

Comment: because im actually interested in what the indexes are of the k smallest numbers in the initial list, (which i didnt specify), can i do this with the heapq?

Comment: @jsky: you could, using `heapq.nsmallest(k, range(len(input_list)), key=inputlist.__getitem__)`.

Comment: @jsky: or use [`numpy.argpartition()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) for a O(n) introselect option: `numpy.argpartition(numpy.array(input_list), k)[:k].tolist()`.

Comment: the argpartition and argsort methods only gave me elements, but the heapq.nsmallest gave me indices. thanks

Answer (score 6):

If the list of the kth smallest numbers doesn't need to be sorted, this can be done in O(n) time with a selection algorithm like [introselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introselect). The standard library doesn't come with one, but NumPy has [`numpy.partition`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html) for the job:

```
partitioned = numpy.partition(l, k)
# The subarray partitioned[:k] now contains the k smallest elements.
```

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take a look at `heapq`:

```
In [109]: L = [random.randint(1,1000) for _ in range(100)]

In [110]: heapq.nsmallest(10, L)
Out[110]: [1, 17, 17, 19, 24, 37, 37, 45, 63, 73]
```

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** this assumes that the list is immutable. If the list is an array and can be modified there are linear methods available.

You can get the complexity down to `O(n * log k)` by using a heap of size `k + 1`.

1. Initially get the first `k` elements into a min-heap.
2. For every subsequent element, add the element as a leaf and heapify.
3. Replace the last element with the next element.

Heapify can be done in logarithmic time and hence the time complexity is as above.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in `O(kn)` with a [selection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm). Once `kn >= n log n`, switch to sorting. That said, the constant on the selection algorithm tends to be a lot higher than the one on quicksort, so you *really* need to compare `i (kn)` and `j (n log n)`. In practice, it's usually more desirable to just sort unless you're dealing with large *n* or very small *k*.

Edit: see comments. It's actually a *lot* better.

Comment: I don't think map-reduce will be any quicker than the max-heap solution.

Comment: Sorting takes O(NlogN), a heap queue gives you O(NlogK), and only takes N + K memory for the lists (one for the input list, one for the heap), plus the original N elements in the list (Python just copies across the references to the heap).

Comment: The selection algorithm doesn't take `O(kn)` unless you're running `k` selections. It's much quicker to select the kth-smallest element and then return a list of everything smaller than that.

Comment: @user2357112: ah, right. Good call. In that case, you can do it in O(n)?

Comment: Yup, it just takes O(n).

Comment: @user2357112: not quite. The devil is in the details there; how do you select the kth smallest item?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: With [introselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introselect), perhaps using the [NumPy implementation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html). Introselect is O(n).

Comment: @user2357112: interesting, had not heard of introselect before. The numpy implementation looks like it would double the memory requirements though, as `partition` basically returns a copy of full array, partitioned, where you'd only need the first k elements.

Comment: @user2357112: related, then, is [Worst-case O(n) algorithm for doing k-selection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7358912) and [How to get indices of N maximum values in a numpy array?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6910641)

Answer (score 1):

Using nsmallest numbers in heapq is less code but if you are looking to implement it yourself this is a simple way to do it. This solution requires looping through the data once only but since heappush and heappop run on O(log n) this algorithm would perform best on smaller numbers of k.

```
import heapq

def getsmallest(arr, k):
    m = [-x for x in l[:k]]
    heapq.heapify(m)
    for num in arr[5:]:
        print num, m
        heapq.heappush(m, max(-num, heapq.heappop(m)))
    return m

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = [1,2,3,52,2,3,1]
    print getsmallest(l, 5)
```