# How to remove n minimum numbers in a list

Tags: python, list, numbers, minimum

I was searching for an answer for this question but couldn't find it. I am posting a answer. Hope it helps someone in the future. Program is tested and works.
n = count of numbers to remove from the list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fastest method of getting k smallest numbers in unsorted list of size N in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33623184/fastest-method-of-getting-k-smallest-numbers-in-unsorted-list-of-size-n-in-pytho)

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers_list = input().split()
n = int(input())

for i in range(len(numbers_list)):  # converts it from string to integers
    numbers_list[i] = int(numbers_list[i])

for i in range(n):
    min_element = min(numbers_list)
    numbers_list.remove(min_element)

for i in range(len(numbers_list)): # converts it again from integers to string
    numbers_list[i] = str(numbers_list[i])

print(", ".join(numbers_list))
```